# PVRTexTool, is there a way to run it on multiple files at once?

Tags: macos, ipad, pvrtc

I am using PVRTexTool to convert png files to pvr files but the tool seems to only be able to run on one file at a time(wont accept *.png as file name).

does anyone know how to run it on a group of files at once?

Its really a hassle to run it on all of my textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shell, run

```
for file in *.png ;  do
     PVRTexToll $file
done
```

(I don't know how to call PVRTeXTool from a command line, so please substitute the second line with a correct version)
This is a general way to feed each file to a command which only accepts one file at a time. See any introduction on shell scripting, e.g. [this discussion of the for loop](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/FlowControl,Expansion,andParsing/FlowControl,Expansion,andParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH4-SW10).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was way simpler then I thought.